# InsertRowBefore() + Defined Range question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a bit of code that inserts a blank row to the top of a sheet and copies data into it.

I also have a defined range on that sheet.

Every time a row is inserted, the defined range moves down a row.

The defined range is helping power a query on another sheet and therefore is always missing the inserted rows.

If i delete the query and use importrange, it works no issue.
However the query doesn't work with importrange.

The easiest fix I'm assuming would be to 'hard-code' the range, but how would i call that in my query?

Here is the query, followed by the same query using importrange.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(STOCK_IN_DATA,"SELECT *" & IF((LEFT(D4,1))="*","WHERE D STARTS WITH '"&RIGHT(D4,LEN(D4)-1)&"' AND C CONTAINS '"&$C4&"' AND E CONTAINS '"&$E4&"' AND F CONTAINS '"&$F4&"' AND G CONTAINS '"&$G4&"' AND H CONTAINS '"&$H4&"'","WHERE C CONTAINS '"&$C4&"' AND D CONTAINS '"&$D4&"' AND E CONTAINS '"&$E4&"' AND F CONTAINS '"&$F4&"' AND G CONTAINS '"&$G4&"' AND H CONTAINS '"&$H4&"'")),)

=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEETNAME","MASTER_IN!$B$1:M"),"SELECT *" & IF((LEFT(D4,1))="*","WHERE D STARTS WITH '"&RIGHT(D4,LEN(D4)-1)&"' AND C CONTAINS '"&$C4&"' AND E CONTAINS '"&$E4&"' AND F CONTAINS '"&$F4&"' AND G CONTAINS '"&$G4&"' AND H CONTAINS '"&$H4&"'","WHERE C CONTAINS '"&$C4&"' AND D CONTAINS '"&$D4&"' AND E CONTAINS '"&$E4&"' AND F CONTAINS '"&$F4&"' AND G CONTAINS '"&$G4&"' AND H CONTAINS '"&$H4&"'")),)
```

What the query does is create a nice little search filter in the cells shown on row 4.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY can use A, B, C columns names only when a reference is used as the first argument. When an array is used as the first argument, as in this case IMPORTRANGE, you should use Col1, Col2, Col3 as column names instead of A, B, C respectively.